# Train, test score disrepancy with datasize

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to apply ML on atomic structures using [descriptors](https://singroup.github.io/dscribe/latest/tutorials/descriptors/soap.html). My problem is that I get very different score values depending on the datasize I use, I suspect that something is wrong with my model, any suggestions would be appreciated. I used dataset [from this paper (Dataset MoS2(single))](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-018-0096-5#Sec16).

Here is the my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  ase
from dscribe.descriptors import SOAP
from dscribe.descriptors import CoulombMatrix

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVR


from ase.io import read
materials = read('structures.xyz', index=':')
materials = materials[:5000]
energies = pd.read_csv('Energy.csv')
energies = np.array(energies['b'])
energies = energies[:5000]

species = ["H", 'Mo', 'S']
rcut = 8.0
nmax = 1
lmax = 1

# Setting up the SOAP descriptor
soap = SOAP(
    species=species,
    periodic=False,
    rcut=rcut,
    nmax=nmax,
    lmax=lmax,
)

coulomb_matrices = soap.create(materials, positions=[[51]]*len(materials)) 

nsamples, nx, ny = coulomb_matrices.shape
d2_train_dataset = coulomb_matrices.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

df = pd.DataFrame(d2_train_dataset)
df['target'] = energies

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X = df.iloc[:, 0:12].values
y = df.iloc[:, 12:].values

st_x = StandardScaler()
st_y = StandardScaler()

X = st_x.fit_transform(X)
y = st_y.fit_transform(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

#krr = GridSearchCV(
#    KernelRidge(kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1),
#    param_grid={"alpha": [1e0, 0.1, 1e-2, 1e-3], "gamma": np.logspace(-2, 2, 5)},
#)

svr = GridSearchCV(
    SVR(kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1),
    param_grid={"C": [1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3], "gamma": np.logspace(-2, 2, 5)},
)

svr = svr.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

print("Training set score: {:.4f}".format(svr.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Test set score: {:.4f}".format(svr.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

and score:

```
Training set score: 0.0414
Test set score: 0.9126
```

Comment: where can we download Energy.csv?

Comment: It's also in the datafile. check second lines as dE. Its also explained in Data Information File

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer to your problem as recreating it would be very cumbersome, but here are some questions to check:

a) You are training on 5 CrossValidation folds (default). First you should check the results of all parameter combinations right after the fitting process with "svr.best_score_" (or more detailed with "svr.cv_results_dict") and see what mean score your folds actually produced. If the score is really is as low as 0.04 (I assume higher is better, which these scores usually do), taking the reciprocal prediction would actually be really accurate! If you know you're always wrong, it's really easy to be right. ;D

b) You could go ahead and just use the svr.best_params_ in order to train again on the whole X_train-set instead of the folds (this can also be achieved with the "refit"-option of RandomSearchCV as well) and then check with the test set again. Here could also be the actual error: The documentation for the score method of GridSearchCV reads: "Return the score on the given data, if the estimator **has been refit**." This is not the case in your gridsearch! Try turning the refit option on. Maybe that works? ... sorry, your code was too cumbersome to be replicated fast, so I didn't check myself ...